# how to pass data from pipeline to dataflow

Tags: azure-data-factory

I have a variable in my pipeline, with the following contents:

```
{
 "childItems":[{"name":"file10"},{"name":"file12"},{"name":"file31"}] //goes on for about 5000 items
}
```

I can pass it to my dataflow as a parameter.

How do I join a dataset from dataflow onto this array?

The other side of the join would look something like this:

```
filename,status
file10,open
file22,closed
file12,pending
```

Expected result would be an inner join of the above along with the json array:

```
file10,open
file12,pending
```

**How do we join on a variable from within the dataflow?**

Comment: I think you can try to using the Data Flow [Expression builder](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/concepts-data-flow-expression-builder),  maybe it can help you achieve that.

Comment: Expressions operate on 1 record at a time

Comment: it would be absurd to run a process on record by record when we have the ability to join multiple datasets within 1 operation

Comment: I also tried many ways, still can not find any way to achieve that.  Just according my knowledge and experience, I think we can not do that.